# Runnable jar works on Mac; gives main class error on Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, jar

I'm producing an app using Eclipse on a Mac, and am using File Export to produce a Runnable Jar. The Runnable Jar files that I produce run happily on my Mac and on another Mac. But on two different Windows machines, they don't. I've looked around for answers, and have tried the following:
1) When I double click on the jar icon nothing happens.
2) When I type
        java -jar Luscinia.jar
at the Command Prompt, I get:
        "Could not find or load main class lusc.net.github.Luscinia"
3) When I type
        java -cp Luscinia.jar lusc.net.github.Luscinia
I get the same error message.

- The JRE on one of the Windows machine (at least) is up to date
  (1.8.0_40). So is the JRE on the Mac.
- The file structure inside my jar does indeed have
  Luscinia.class nested inside github, net and lusc directories.
- The manifest contains the lines:
     Class-Path: .
     Main-Class: lusc.net.github.Luscinia
  (& it contains two blank lines at the bottom)
- Other jar's are working well on the two Windows machines.
- And to emphasise again, it works perfectly well on two Mac machines.

Any ideas?

- I checked whether the EOL character had an effect. Changing it to Windows \r\n didn't have any effect. (Thanks to RealSkeptic for the idea).

Comment: Make sure the manifest file has CR and LF at the end of each line. On the Mac it may be just CR or just LF.

Comment: Thanks for that idea, but no luck. I changed the option in Eclipse to Windows EOL (CR LF), cleaned and rebuilt. I checked the manifest using   od -c MANIFEST.MF  , and all lines ended /r/n. But I still get the same errors.

Comment: Also, the error indicated that the Windows JVM *had* parsed the manifest (it knew that it had to look for lusc.net.github.Luscinia), but it couldn't find/load it...

Comment: I can't be sure if it was looking for `Luscinia` or for `Luscinia` with a few linefeeds at its end (and how this would look when copied from Windows to StackOverflow). But anyway, as you eliminated that, that's settled. Did you try creating a regular jar (not runnable) to see if there is any success?

Comment: I would remove `Class-Path: .` from your manifest and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your class doesn't attempt to load a Mac specific class that is not available in the windows JRE (vendor private classes ? like com.sun classes on windows) or it's not missing dependencies in the classpath necessary to the main class ?

If one of your dependant class fails to load when the main class is being class loaded (in static blocks for example), it makes it fail to load the importing class as well and you can have that problem.

In any case, having the source of the main class could help figure out the problem.

Comment: I believe this would better server as a comment since it does not answer the question, but gives a suggestion to try.

Comment: Well if it turns out the problem is actually what I describe, wouldn't that serve as an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by DarkRift was correct:

Hidden in one file was a reference to a com.apple... class that was superfluous and, critically, platform specific.

In this case, when I got the error message:

```
Could not find or load main class lusc.net.github.Luscinia
```

It meant "Could not load" rather than "Could not find". Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: sure,  sorry for missing that!